# How to specify a integer value using % in print statement in python?

Tags: python, integer

Please fix this code, it is giving an error-

```
print("\nANSWER THE QUESTIONS BELOW-\n")
name=input("What is your name: ")
age=int(input("What is your age: "))
gender=input("What is your gender: ")
name = name.upper()
print("\nYour name is %s, your age is %d, and you are a %s" %name %age %gender)
print("\n Thank You!!")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Also `%` formatting in python is fairly old, and has been improved with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and `f-string`s.

Answer (score 0):

You supply a single tuple of values, rather than repeating the `%` operator.

```
print("\nYour name is %s, your age is %d, and you are a %s" % (name, age , gender))
```

If you really wanted to *chain* the operators, each one would have to return a string suitable as an argument for the next. This involves escaping a *lot* of `%`s.

```
 name = "Bob"
 age = 20
 gender = "male"
 print("\nYour name is %s, your age is %%d, and you are a %%%%s" %name %age %gender)
```

Each operation replaces `%%` with `%`, so

1. The first operation, `"..." % name`, produces

   ```
   "\nYour name is bob, your age is %d, and you are a %%s"
   ```
2. The second operation, `"..." % age`, produces

   ```
   "\nYour name is bob, your age is 10, and you are a %s"
   ```

The final operation `"..." % gender produces the expected string

```
    "\nYour name is bob, your age is 10, and you are a male"
```

Comment: while the chaining version is correct, I cannot emphasise how wrong it feels.

Comment: @ljmc Oh, it's absolutely horrible. I just meant to show that each application of `%` produces another `str` value, which itself can be used with `%` (if it has the appropriate content).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your print statement with any of the following:

```py
print("\nYour name is %s, your age is %d, and you are a %s" % (name, age, gender))
```

```py
print("\nYour name is {}, your age is {}, and you are a {}".format(name, age, gender))
```

```py
print("\nYour name is {name}, your age is {age}, and you are a {gender}".format(name=name, age=age, gender=gender))
```

```py
print(f"\nYour name is {name}, your age is {age}, and you are a {gender}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tuple:

```py
print("\nYour name is %s, your age is %d, and you are a %s" % (name, age , gender))
```

Or, with `str.format`:

```py
print("\nYour name is {}, your age is {}, and you are a {}".format(name, age, gender))
```

Or, with an f-string:

```py
print(f"\nYour name is {name}, your age is {age}, and you are a {gender}")
```